# Can't receive socketio emit fired from inside redis server

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

im emitting from redis server to node.js (socket.io) than receiving it on socket.io client.

server.js file

```
var server = require('http').Server();

var io = require("socket.io")(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
      }
  });
var Redis = require('ioredis');

var redis = new Redis();

redis.subscribe('test-channal');

redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log("Message recived");
    console.log(message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);

    io.emit("test", "test-world");
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.emit("hey", "world");
  });

server.listen(3000);
```

client side

```
<!-- <script scr='http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script> -->
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.0.0/socket.io.min.js" ></script>

    <script>

        var socket = io("http://localhost:3000");
//this gives output
        socket.on("hello", (arg) => {
            console.log(arg); // world
        });
//but this doesnt
        socket.on("test", (arg) => {
            console.log(arg); // world
        });

    </script>
```

also socketio-client won't work when

```
<!-- <script scr='http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script> -->
```

but it works fine with cdn.

[and this is what i get on client-side console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OaSG.png)

only 'world' is output

both emits are committed but somehow on the client-side im only receiving the emit outside redis.on methoed

Comment: Are you for sure getting a `Message recived` in the console? When do you publish a redis message? Also I noticed you're subscribing to `test-channal`, not sure if that's a typo.

Comment: yup in redis console im. inside the routes file also the test0channal is inside the route file
```
Route::get('/', function () {
    $data = [
        'event' =>  'UserSignedUp',
        'data' => [
            'username' => 'hamid'
        ]
    ];

    Redis::publish('test-channal', json_encode($data));
        // Cache::put('foo','bar',10);
        // return Cache::get('foo');
        // Redis::get('name');
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Comment: What specifically is the issue? Is the socket.io broadcast not working or are you not able to receive the redis message?

Comment: well the issue is you see the function in server,js file where i have said ``` redis.redis.subscribe('test-channal');```
 than ```redis.on``` method 
when i try to socket emit inside redis.on method it gets emitted but somehow i cant catch it on client side where as if i socket emit outside redis.on method i resive it in client and the method get exectued, where i have console log arg it get printed in console

Comment: How do you know it gets emitted if you can't receive it? Also you are writing them differently—if you use `io.emit` instead of `socket.emit` for the second one, does it still work?

Comment: well i debugged it by consoling one msg before and after the first emit
as For that well, i found it on socketio documentation 
also socket is the arguemnt there
```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.emit("hey", "world");
  })
```